# Postgresql random row assignment

Tags: postgresql

I have got 2 tables

```
Student

|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |     studentname  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     studentA     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     studentB     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |     studentC     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |     studentD     |
|---------------------|------------------|  

Chair

|---------------------|------------------|
|      id             |     chairname    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     chairA       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     chairB       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |     chairC       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I need a query to randomly assign a student to a chair in postgresql. Note that there can be more chairs than students or vice versa. In case there is more student than chairs, students not assigned will have null value in chair.

For the above tables we should have a result like

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      studentname    |     chairname    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          studentA   |     chairC       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          studentB   |     chairA       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          studentC   |     chairB       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          studentD   |     NULL         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

OR

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      studentname    |     chairname    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          studentA   |     chairA       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          studentB   |     chairC       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          studentC   |     NULL         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          studentD   |     chairB       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Any idea how this can be done in postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `ROW_NUMBER` with a random ordering to assign student IDs to the various chairs:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT chairname, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RANDOM()) rn
    FROM Chair
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT studentname, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM Student
)

SELECT
    s.studentname,
    c.chairname
FROM cte2 s
LEFT JOIN cte1 c
    ON s.rn = c.rn;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that I actually generate a row number sequence across both tables, including the `Student` table.  This is to ensure that we always compare row number values which would match between both tables.

Edit: Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `FULL OUTER JOIN` to generally handle the case where the number of students exceed chairs or vice-versa.

Comment: That is really a nice solution

Comment: Since there is the case of more chairs than students, I think that a FULL JOIN is more suitable.

Comment: Great solution. Works. Thanks